# Custom Window info on google map using swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift4.1

i am write this method for custom window info on google map in ios swift 4.1 but the window dosn't show on google map

and i am also set delegates but no results

```
 func mapView(_mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?{

    let infoWindow: InfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("InfoWindow", owner: self.view, options: nil)!.first! as! InfoWindow

    infoWindow.numberCarLabel.text = "TLA-618"
    infoWindow.dateLabel.text = "2018-05-02 10:39:43"
    infoWindow.digreeLabel.text = "94"
    infoWindow.addressLabel.text = "Sunrise Appartments, Marine Promenade, Karachi"
    infoWindow.kilometterLabel.text = "0"

    return infoWindow

}
```

Comment: your function is called?

Comment: no not working on google map,

Comment: can you share your viewController code?

Comment: Clip number :   0IJKVV
Direct URL :   http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IJKVV

Comment: this is Code link cell it

Comment: bro you see it code where i am doing mistake in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after review your code, first of all you have a typo in the delegate function name

the correct one is:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
     let infoWindow: InfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("InfoWindow", owner: self.view, options: nil)!.first! as! InfoWindow

     infoWindow.numberCarLabel.text = "TLA-618"
     infoWindow.dateLabel.text = "2018-05-02 10:39:43"
     infoWindow.digreeLabel.text = "94"
     infoWindow.addressLabel.text = "Sunrise Appartments, Marine Promenade, Karachi"
     infoWindow.kilometterLabel.text = "0"

     return infoWindow
}
```

You have also an issue here in `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` you don't need to re assign your mapview every time `CLLocationManager` report position

replace your `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` implementation by this one

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation = locations.last

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude,
                                          longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 13.0)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: I mean can you share with me again your code after this fix? @RehanMeo

Comment: Clip number :   0IJKVX
Direct URL :   http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IJKVX

Comment: @RehanMeo please copy and paste my   `func mapView(_mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?` implementation your issue is a typo in this `_mapView` part, should be  `_ mapView` with a space between `_` and `mapView` please copy and paste my implementation from my answer

Comment: Thank bro solve it problem 

again thanks. you are great person

Comment: @RehanMeo your welcome, please remember accept my answer is the gray checkmark in the left side of my answer